# acronyms font size

Tags: fontsize, acronyms

I am using the acronym package and the acronyms font size is smaller than the document text. But I have some acronyms that include small letters like (QoS). I used the following in the definition:

```
\acro{QoS}[$\mathrm{QoS}$]{Quality-of-Service}
```

and when I am calling the acronym, I use `\acffont{QoS}` but the font size is larger than the font size of other acronyms and it is the same as the normal text font size in the document. How I can fix this to get the same font size as the normal acronyms.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), that is, code without irrelevant parts for the question,  but still compilable (i.e, including  `\documentclass`, `\usepackage{<your package for the acronyms>}`, `\end{document}`, etc.)  **and** it shows your problem, and it shows only this problem.

Comment: Why `$\mathrm{QoS}$` instead of just `QoS`?

Comment: $\mathrm{QoS}$ this to provide "o" with small letter font. if we did not use it when you call the acronym it will show QOS. Any help on how to use the acronym package such that the small fonts in the acronym will appear small